# what is the correct regexp for mysql filter in fail2ban?

Tags: security, regular-expression, mysql, fail2ban

I use the default filter file `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/mysqld-auth.conf` for fail2ban service. But there are some errors in file `/var/log/fail2ban.log` as:

```
Found a match for '150815 10:42:54 [Warning] Access denied for user
'root'@'124.248.35.228' (using password: NO)' but no valid date/time found
for '150815 10:42:54 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'124.248.35.228'
(using password: NO)'. Please contact the author in order to get support
for this format
```

As the default regexp for mysql in fail2ban in the filter file, seems ok:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s(\d{6} \s?\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )?\[Warning\] Access denied for user '\w+'@'<HOST>' (to database '[^']*'|\(using password: (YES|NO)\))*\s*$
```

I need to mention that I config mysql in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` as so:

```
log-error               = /var/log/mysql/mysql.err
log-warning             = 2
```

What is the correct regexp for mysql in fail2ban?

Comment: How does the log lines to be matched look like, could you give examples? It seems MySQL does log the time in another format.